# How to solve this definite integration $\int_0^L{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{k}{P(x)}\right)^2}dx}$?

Tags: definite-integrals

Is there a way to further simplify or solve this integral?

$$\int_0^L{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{k}{P(x)}\right)^2}dx}$$
where $k$, $L$ are constant; $P(x)$ is a function defined over $0$ to $L$.

$P(x)$ takes the form:

$$P(x)=\frac{(y_2-y_1)*2}{L}x+y_1\quad \textrm{when }x\in\left[0-\frac{L}{2}\right]$$
$$P(x)=\frac{(y_1-y_2)*2}{L}\left(x-\frac{L}{2}\right)+y_2\quad \textrm{when }x\in\left[\frac{L}{2}-L\right]$$
where $y_1$ and $y_2$ are also constants.

I have tried out MATHEMATICA, but it does not give me a useful result.

Comment: What does $x = [ \frac{L}{2} - L ]$ mean ? Also, an integral is not an equation.

Comment: $x=[\frac{L}{2}-L]$ means x takes value from $\frac{L}{2}$ to $L$. 

And yes, I will edit the description. I want to have a simplified form.

Comment: @Rebellos perhaps, $x\in\left[\frac{L}{2},L\right]$? The hyphen seems ambiguous and is not standard interval notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reducing the noise let $\alpha=\frac{2(y_2-y_1)}{L}$, then we split up the integral from $[0,\frac{L}{2}]$ and $[\frac{L}{2},L]$, after a substitution we get;
$$I=\int_0^{\frac{L}{2}}\sqrt{1+(\frac{k}{\alpha x +y_1})^2}+\int_{\frac{L}{2}}^{L}\sqrt{1+(\frac{k}{-\alpha (x-\frac{L}{2}) +y_2})^2}=$$
$$\int_0^{\frac{L}{2}}\sqrt{1+(\frac{k}{\alpha x+y_1})^2}dx+\int_0^{\frac{L}{2}}\sqrt{1+(\frac{k}{-\alpha x+y_2})^2}dx$$
Letting 
$$\frac{\alpha x+y_1}{k} = u \qquad \frac{-\alpha x+y_1}{k} = v$$
$$dx=\frac{k}{\alpha}du \qquad dx=\frac{k}{-\alpha}dv$$
$$I=\frac{2k}{y_2-y_1}\int_{\frac{y_1}{k}}^{\frac{y_2}{k}}\sqrt{\frac{x^2+1}{x^2}}dx$$
Try [mathematica](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20sqrt((x%5E2%2B1)%2Fx%5E2)dx)
now.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Although there's one typo, but I get the idea.